# React class not rendering

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpacker

I'm trying to follow along with the reactjs tic tac toe tutorial, but when I try to render the pages and I have this code

```
    import React from 'react'
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
    import Game from '../components/Game'
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        ReactDOM.render(
            console.log("render is working"),
            <Game />,
            document.getElementById('root'),
        );
    })
```

and the Game class looks like

```
    import React from 'react'
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
    import Board from './Board'

    class Game extends React.Component {
        render() {
            console.log("Hooray, the game is working")
            return (
                <div className="game">
                    <div className="game-board">
                        <Board />
                    </div>
                    <div className="game-info">
                        <div>{/* status */}</div>
                        <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default Game
```

The 'render is working prints to the console but the console log that says "Hooray, the game is working" doesn't show up, so it seems like the 
Game class isn't getting rendered for some reason. I'm using ruby on rails with the built in webpacker to load all the javascripts

Comment: Why the console.log ?!

Comment: Take the log out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause calling `console.log` evaluates to `undefined` you are basically doing:

```
ReactDOM.render(
   undefined, // <- react component
   <Game />, // <- target 
   document.getElementById('root'), // < - useless
);
```

I'm surprised that `ReactDOM.render` is not throwing an error although you are passing completely useless arguments to it.

Answer (score 1):

`ReactDOM.render()` takes 2 arguments: component, and mounting DOM element. You are passing a `console.log` for the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

For one, why do you have your `ReactDom.render(...)` wrapped in that event listener? 
Two, why are you passing the `ReactDom.render(...)` a `console.log()`? It should only take two arguments: a component, and the element it should be appended to. Try removing the `console.log()` and if that still doesn't work, try removing the event listener that wraps your `ReactDoom.render(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the console log from the ReactDOM render call.

If I need to render in a component, I can do it as such.

```
<div>
  .....
  {console.log('Inline console in render method')}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your render should be as follows:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.getElementById('root);
```

Assuming your child component is passed as 'export default Game' and your Id of your HTML base file is 'root'.

Render only takes two arguments. The first being the component being passed in and the second is the target in which it should place itself. You should only need to do this step at your 'index.js' file. Nowhere else.